# Not all documents are indexed with ElasticSearch and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch 1.1.0 (I was running 1.2.0 but had issues with a ElasticSearch plugin) and MongoDB 2.6.1. I've installed them using the tutorial provided at [enter link description here](https://coderwall.com/p/sy1qcw). When I create an index using

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_river/tenders/_meta" -d '{       
    "type": "mongodb",
    "mongodb": {
        "servers": [
            { "host": "127.0.0.1", "port": 27017 }
        ],
        "options": { "secondary_read_preference": true },
        "db": "tenderdb",
        "collection": "tenders"
    },
    "index": {
        "name": "tendersidx",
        "type": "page"
    }
}'
```

Indexing starts fine of the collection but it only indexes a part of the collection. E.g. the collection has at the moment 5184 records while only 1060 are indexed.

Comment: so how is anyone supposed to help you with that set of information?

Comment: ElasticSearch rivers only monitor changes in the other data store; your river should only track documents added to the collection after the river has been set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Avish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119694/avish)'s comment did the trick, he wrote: "ElasticSearch rivers only monitor changes in the other data store; your river should only track documents added to the collection after the river has been set up."