# MongoDb document not completely indexed in Elastic search

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I have created a MongoDb collection with documents in them, an example of a document is presented below.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("53837eed557acd39628b4cdf"),
    "userid": null,
    "importdate": ISODate("2014-05-26T17:50:37.0Z"),
    "documentnumber": "174953-2014",
    "source": "ted",
    "typeoftender": "public",
    "categories": {
        "0": ObjectId("527baa62557acd1669eb992d") 
    },
    "data": {
        "oj": "100",
        "ol": "bg",
        "cy": "bg",
        "dt": ISODate("2014-06-30T22:00:00.0Z"),
        "heading": "01302",
        "ti": {
            "bg": "Услуги по програмиране на системен софтуер и потребителски софтуерни средства",
            "cs": "Programování systémového a uživatelského programového vybavení",
            "da": "Programmeringsservice i forbindelse med systemer og brugerprogrammel",
            "de": "Programmierung von System- und Anwendersoftware",
            "el": "Υπηρεσίες προγραμματισμού λογισμικών συστήματος και χρήστη",
            "en": "Programming services of systems and user software",
            "es": "Servicios de programación de sistemas y software de usuario",
            "et": "Süsteemide ja kasutajatarkvara programmeerimine",
            "fi": "Varus- ja käyttäjäohjelmiston ohjelmointipalvelut",
            "fr": "Services de programmation de systèmes et de logiciels utilitaires",
            "ga": "Programming services of systems and user software",
            "hr": "Usluge programiranja sustava i korisničke podrške",
            "hu": "Rendszer- és felhasználói szoftverek programozási szolgáltatásai",
            "it": "Servizi di programmazione di software di sistemi e di utente",
            "lt": "Programavimo paslaugos, susijusios su sistemomis ir vartotojo programine įranga",
            "lv": "Sistēmu un lietotāju programmatūras programmēšanas pakalpojumi",
            "mt": "Servizzi ta' programmizzar tas-sistemi u tas-software ta' l-utenti",
            "nl": "Programmering van systeem- en gebruikerssoftware",
            "pl": "Usługi programowania oprogramowania systemowego i dla użytkownika",
            "pt": "Serviços de programação de sistemas e de software para o utilizador",
            "ro": "Servicii de programare de sisteme informatice şi software utilitare",
            "sk": "Programovanie systémového a používateľského softvéru",
            "sl": "Storitve programiranja sistemske in uporabniške programske opreme",
            "sv": "Programmering av system- och användarprogram" 
        },
        "tw": {
            "bg": "София",
            "cs": "Sofie",
            "da": "Sofia",
            "de": "Sofia",
            "el": "Σόφια",
            "en": "Sofia",
            "es": "Sofía",
            "et": "Sofia",
            "fi": "Sofia",
            "fr": "Sofia",
            "ga": "Sóifia",
            "hr": "Sofija",
            "hu": "Szófia",
            "it": "Sofia",
            "lt": "Sofija",
            "lv": "Sofija",
            "mt": "Sofija",
            "nl": "Sofia",
            "pl": "Sofia",
            "pt": "Sófia",
            "ro": "Sofia",
            "sk": "Sofia",
            "sl": "Sofija",
            "sv": "Sofia" 
        },
        "rc": "BG411",
        "cpv": {
            "0": "72211000" 
        } 
    },
    "document": {
        "da": "<p>Direktiv 2004\/18\/EF<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Del I: Ordregivende myndighed<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style=\"col [...]",
        "de": "<p>Richtlinie 2004\/18\/EG<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Abschnitt I: Öffentlicher Auftraggeber<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" [...]",
        "en": "<p>Directive 2004\/18\/EC<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Section I: Contracting authority<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style= [...]",
        "es": "<p>Directiva 2004\/18\/CE<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Apartado I: Poder adjudicador<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style=\"co [...]",
        "fi": "<p>Direktiivi 2004\/18\/EY<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">I kohta: Hankintaviranomainen<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style=\"c [...]",
        "fr": "<p>Directive 2004\/18\/CE<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Section I: Pouvoir adjudicateur<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style=\" [...]",
        "el": "<p>Οδηγία 2004\/18\/ΕΚ<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Τμήμα I: Αναθέτουσα αρχή<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style=\"color:blac [...]",
        "it": "<p>Direttiva 2004\/18\/CE<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Sezione I: Amministrazione aggiudicatrice<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomar [...]",
        "nl": "<p>Richtlijn 2004\/18\/EG<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Afdeling I: Aanbestedende dienst<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style= [...]",
        "pt": "<p>Directiva 2004\/18\/CE<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Secção I: Autoridade adjudicante<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style= [...]",
        "sv": "<p>Direktiv 2004\/18\/EG<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Avsnitt I: Upphandlande myndighet<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style= [...]",
        "cs": "<p>Směrnice 2004\/18\/ES<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Oddíl I: Veřejný zadavatel<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style=\"color: [...]",
        "et": "<p>Direktiiv 2004\/18\/EÜ<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">I osa: Hankija<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style=\"color:black\">I.1) [...]",
        "hu": "<p>2004\/18\/EK irányelv<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">I. szakasz: Ajánlatkérő<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style=\"color:bla [...]",
        "lt": "<p>Direktyva 2004\/18\/EB<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">I dalis: Perkančioji organizacija<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style [...]",
        "lv": "<p>Direktīva 2004\/18\/EK<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">I iedaļa: Līgumslēdzēja iestāde<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style=\" [...]",
        "mt": "<p>Direttiva 2004\/18\/KE<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Taqsima I: Awtorità kontraenti<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style=\"c [...]",
        "pl": "<p>Dyrektywa 2004\/18\/WE<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Sekcja I: Instytucja zamawiająca<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style= [...]",
        "sk": "<p>Smernica 2004\/18\/ES<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Oddiel I: Verejný obstarávateľ<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style=\"co [...]",
        "sl": "<p>Direktiva 2004\/18\/ES<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Oddelek I: Naročnik<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style=\"color:black\" [...]",
        "ga": "<p>Treoir 2004\/18\/CE<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Alt I: Údarás conarthachta<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style=\"color:bl [...]",
        "bg": "<p>Директива 2004\/18\/ЕО<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Раздел І: Възлагащ орган<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style=\"color:b [...]",
        "ro": "<p>Directiva 2004\/18\/CE<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Secțiunea I: Autoritatea contractantă<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" s [...]",
        "hr": "<p>Direktiva 2004\/18\/EZ<\/p><div class=\"grseq\"><p class=\"tigrseq\">Odjeljak I.: Javni naručitelj<\/p><div class=\"mlioccur\"><span class=\"nomark\" style=\"co [...]" 
      }
}
```

Once elastic search is done indexing it only stores

```
{
        _index: tendersidx
        _type: page
        _id: 53837eec557acd39628b4c2b
        _score: 1
        _source: {
            document: {
                da: <p>Direktiv 2004/18/EF</p><div class="grseq"><p class="tigrseq">Del I: Ordregivende myndighed</p><div class="mlioccur"><span class="nomark" style="color:black">I.1)</span><span class="timark" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">Navn, adresser og kontaktpunkt(er)</span><div class="txtmark" style="color:black"><p><p class="addr">Turun kaupunki<br><br>Linnankatu 55 K, 2 krs. / PL 630<br>20101<br>TurkuFINLAND<br>+358 449075222<br>karolus.haarte@turku.fi</p></p></p><p><p class="ft"><b>Bud eller ansøgninger om deltagelse skal sendes til:</b></p><p class="addr">Turun kaupunki<br><br>https://tarjouspalvelu.fi/turku/?id=17775&tpk=93d33e8c-86aa-40c6-8c60-16d511c61a9a<br></p></p></div></div></span></div><div class="grseq"><p class="tigrseq">Del II: Kontraktens genstand</p><div class="mlioccur"><span class="nomark" style="color:black">II.1)</span><span class="timark" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">Beskrivelse</span></div></span><div class="mlioccur"><span class="nomark" style="color:black">II.1.6)</span><span class="timark" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">CPV-glossaret (common procurement vocabulary)</span><div class="txtmark" style="color:black"><p>85000000</p></div></div></span><div class="mlioccur"><span class="nomark" style="color:black"></span><span class="timark" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">Beskrivelse</span><div class="txtmark" style="color:black"><p>Sundhedsvæsen og sociale foranstaltninger.</p></div></div></span></div><div class="grseq"><p class="tigrseq">Del IV: Procedure</p><div class="mlioccur"><span class="nomark" style="color:black">IV.3)</span><span class="timark" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">Administrative oplysninger</span></div></span><div class="mlioccur"><span class="nomark" style="color:black">IV.3.3)</span><span class="timark" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">Vilkår for adgang til specifikationer og yderligere dokumenter eller beskrivende dokumenter</span></div></span><div class="mlioccur"><span class="nomark" style="color:black">IV.3.4)</span><span class="timark" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">Frist for modtagelse af bud eller ansøgninger om deltagelse</span><div class="txtmark" style="color:black"><p>11.8.2014 - 14:00</p></div></div></span><div class="mlioccur"><span class="nomark" style="color:black">IV.3.6)</span><span class="timark" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">Sprog, der må benyttes ved afgivelse af bud eller ansøgninger om deltagelse</span><div class="txtmark" style="color:black"><p>finsk.</p></div></div></span></div>
                }
        source: ted
        _id: 53837eec557acd39628b4c2b
        documentnumber: 175084-2014
        importdate: 2014-05-26T17:50:36.000Z
        data: {
            dt: 2014-08-10T22:00:00.000Z
        cpv: [
            85000000
        ]
        cy: fi
        td: 3
        rc: FI183
        ti: {
            sl: Storitve na področju zdravstva in socialnega varstva
            hr: Usluge u području zdravstva i socijalne skrbi
            sk: Zdravotnícka a sociálna pomoc
            ro: Servicii de sănătate şi servicii de asistenţă socială
            da: Sundhedsvæsen og sociale foranstaltninger
            it: Servizi sanitari e di assistenza sociale
            mt: Servizzi dwar saħħa ta' xogħol soċjali
            hu: Egészségügyi és szociális gondozási szolgáltatások
            lv: Veselības un sociālie pakalpojumi
            lt: Sveikatos priežiūros ir socialinio darbo paslaugos
            ga: Health and social work services
            cs: Zdravotní a sociální péče
            de: Dienstleistungen des Gesundheits- und Sozialwesens
            el: Υγειονομικές και κοινωνικές υπηρεσίες
            fi: Terveyspalvelut ja sosiaalitoimen palvelut
            pt: Serviços de saúde e acção social
            pl: Usługi w zakresie zdrowia i opieki społecznej
            sv: Hälso- och sjukvård samt socialvård
            bg: Услуги на здравеопазването и социалните дейности
            fr: Services de santé et services sociaux
            en: Health and social work services
            et: Tervishoiu ja sotsiaaltöö teenused
            es: Servicios de salud y asistencia social
            nl: Gezondheidszorg en maatschappelijk werk
        }
        ty: 1
        nc: 4
        tw: {
            sl: Turku
            hr: Turku
            sk: Turku
            ro: Turku
            da: Turku
            it: Turku
            mt: Turku
            hu: Turku
            lv: Turku
            lt: Turku
            ga: Turku
            cs: Turku
            de: Turku
            el: Turku
            fi: Turku
            pt: Turku
            pl: Turku
            sv: Åbo
            bg: Турку
            fr: Turku
            en: Turku
            et: Turu
            es: Turku
            nl: Turku
        }
        ol: fi
        oj: 100
        ds: 0.00000000 1400623200
        pr: 1
        heading: 01302
        }
        userid: null
        categories: false
        typeoftender: public
        }
    }
```

As you can see the elasticssearch has only indexed part of "document", the "da" element.

The index is created with the following command:

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_river/tenders/_meta" -d '
{
    "type": "mongodb",
    "mongodb": {
        "servers": [
            { "host": "127.0.0.1", "port": 27017 }
        ],
        "options": { "secondary_read_preference": true },
        "db": "tenderdb",
        "collection": "tenders"
    },
    "index": {
        "name": "tendersidx",
        "type": "page"
    }
}'
```

The process that makes database insertion work is:
1) Download data from a server
2) Extract the data downloaded from the server
3) Insert the data into MongoDB collection
4) Download the meta data from the server (this part contains the "document" information)
5) Extract the downloaded meta data
6) Insert the extracted meta data into MongoDB collection. The meta data is stored in various files, each language has its own file. The "da" - danish is the first document that is inserted.

MongoDb: 2.6.1

ElasticSearch: 1.1.0

Plugins:

[elasticsearch-mapper-attachments version 2.0.0](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments)
[elasticsearch-river-mongodb version 2.0.0](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb)

Anyone has an idea why the other entries in the mongo "document", besides "da" are not available in the eleasticsearch dataset?

Comment: It would help if you detailed how you indexing from MongoDB to Elasticsearch (plugin? custom code?). If custom code then include that too, along with the versions of MongoDB and Elasticsearch.

Comment: @JohnPetrone thanks for pointing out the missing information, I have added the information you have suggested.

Comment: Can you provide a matching set of documents as opposed to two different ones? When you provide different example docs (mongodb one is "documentnumber": "174953-2014", elasticsearch one is documentnumber: 175084-2014) it's difficult to debug. This will be easier if you can look at each document field by field to see what's going in correctly and what's not. You're also not providing the full "document" sub-document in mongodb - hard to debug that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not all documents are indexed with ElasticSearch and MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856868/not-all-documents-are-indexed-with-elasticsearch-and-mongodb)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The other thread mentioned that from the 5000 records only 1900 records gets indexed. This thread describes a different problem: from the records that are indexed some elements are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic Search and Java was running out of memory. Increasing the amount of memory assigned to Java solved the issue for me.